# Add thumbnail to recent posts widget using filters

Tags: widgets, recent-posts

I want to add thumbnail to WordPress default recent posts widget, and I want to do it using any available filter.
Is there any filter know to this subject/topic

Comment: There is no direct filter to modify/add any data in the default WordPress recent posts widget.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it through the `the_title` filter. We can limit the scope to the *Recent Posts* widget, by initialize it within the `widget_posts_args` filter and then remove it again after the loop.

```
/**
 * Recent Posts Widget: Append Thumbs
 */
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', function( array $args )
{
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_prepend_thumbnail', 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'loop_end',  'wpse_clean_up' );
    return $args;
} );
```

where we define

```
function wpse_prepend_thumbnail( $title, $post_id )
{
    static $instance = 0;

    // Append thumbnail every second time (odd)
    if( 1 === $instance++ % 2 && has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) )
        $title = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) . $title;

    return $title;
}
```

and

```
function wpse_clean_up( \WP_Query $q )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_add_thumnail', 10 );
}
```

Note that because of this check in the `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts::widget()` method:

```
get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID()
```

the `the_title` filter is applied two times for each item. That's why we only apply the thumbnail appending for the odd cases.

Also note that this approach assumes non empty titles.

Otherwise it's more flexible to just create/extend a new widget to our needs instead.

Comment: Is there a way to select only post type "post?" My widget has been selecting a custom post type as well that does not need to be showing. The weird thing is that it has only been happening on Category pages, posts and pages show correctly.

Comment: You might have some plugin/theme code that's modifying your widget output, e.g. via `pre_get_posts` hook. You can adjust the `$args` in the `widget_posts_args` filter, e.g. `$args['post_type'] = 'post';` @jonbon

Comment: @birgire awesome, I'm going to try that now.

Comment: @birgire so it should look like add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', function( array $args['post_type'] = 'post'; )

Comment: e.g. `add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', function( $args ) { $args['post_type'] = 'post'; return $args; } );` if that doesn't work you might need to use the `pre_get_posts` hook with some late priority, to override the code that's modifying your `WP_Query` in the widget. But better yet to find the code in your setup that's changing this. This would be better served as a new question. @jonbon

Comment: @birgire I went ahead and started another question because this solution didn't work. I'm assuming it needs pre_get although I'm not familiar with using it http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249830/recent-posts-widget-using-filters-is-selecting-additional-post-types

Answer (score 0):

**No** filter available.

---

Checking the [`/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-recent-posts-widget.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_recent_posts/widget/) the following is the code that outputs the widget

```
$r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
    'posts_per_page'      => $number,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
) ) );

if ($r->have_posts()) :
?>
<?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
<?php if ( $title ) {
    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
} ?>
<ul>
<?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
    <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
        <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
<?php
// Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Which obviously has no filter to insert some thumbnail or anything in the loop.