# Best way to add image to recent posts widget?

Tags: functions, filters, post-thumbnails, recent-posts

I want to add an image/thumbnail to the Wordpress recent posts widget.

[This is the only related question that I've seen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235165/add-thumbnail-to-recent-posts-widget-using-filters) and it uses filters and seems to be a bit round-about. I don't want to install an entire plugin for this. What is the easiest way to just add the featured image above the recent posts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to get answered here that is different than the linked duplicate question. The answers there are still relevant being answered just 3 months ago. You'll either need to get your hands dirty or find a plugin that does the dirty work for you.

Comment: That question was specifically for using a filter. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without a roundabout filter etc.

Comment: Yes, without filter you can create your own widget, base on the informations of the other question.